# Nested dictionary find key with highest or most frequency value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have many lists that contain dictionary looks like this:

```
a = [{'health': {'medical_emergency': 1.0}}, {'scitech': {'technology': 1.0, 'computer': 1.0, 'programming': 1.0}}]
b = [{'politics': {'government': 1.0}}, {'travel': {'vacation': 1.0, 'traveling': 1.0, 'tourism': 1.0}}, {'finance': {'business': 1.0}}]
c = [{'sports': {'sports': 2.0}}, {'health': {'exercise': 1.0}}]
```

The structure is `{class: {keyword: number_of_times_the_keyword_occur}}`

They are in different lengths. How can I get the class with the highest scores of the value or the class with the most frequency value?

For example,

in a:  it should return scitech, because it has three keywords (technology, computer, programming) in the scitech, and health only has one keyword.

in b:  it should return travel, the reason is same as case a.

in c: it should return sports, because in the sports class, the keyword 'sport' occurs two times, but the health class the keyword(exercise) only happens once

Here is what I've tried:

```
import operator
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(max(a[i].items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0])
```

But it will only return all the key.

Comment: What output would you expect if there is a tie with two inner keywords. Is the sum of the nums relevant? BTW, this is an odd data structure: are all the outer dicts singletons, i.e. have only one key?

Comment: `max(a[i].items(), ...` will only find `{class: {keyword: number_of_times_the_keyword_occur}}` one dict.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yes, and yes, there also some data has only one key.

Comment: @Tserenjamts I know. Because it can only count the number of the value, but there is sub dictionary in my value. I put the code just want to show what I've tried...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
a = [{'health': {'medical_emergency': 1.0}}, {'scitech': {'technology': 1.0, 'computer': 1.0, 'programming': 1.0}}]
b = [{'politics': {'government': 1.0}}, {'travel': {'vacation': 1.0, 'traveling': 1.0, 'tourism': 1.0}}, {'finance': {'business': 1.0}}]
c = [{'sports': {'sports': 2.0}}, {'health': {'exercise': 1.0}}]

def get_max(l):
    cnt = []
    for d in l:
        for k,v in d.items():
            cnt.append([k,sum(v.values())])
    return sorted(cnt,key = lambda x : x[1],reverse=True)

print(get_max(a))
print(get_max(b))
print(get_max(c))
```

Output:

```
[['scitech', 3.0], ['health', 1.0]]
[['travel', 3.0], ['politics', 1.0], ['finance', 1.0]]
[['sports', 2.0], ['health', 1.0]]
```

You can get the values you want at the first element